# New activity after 100% in ProgressDialog

Tags: java, android, progressdialog

I've got this code:

```
@Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            progressDoalog = new ProgressDialog(Hack.this);
            progressDoalog.setMax(100);
            progressDoalog.setMessage("Its loading....");
            progressDoalog.setTitle("ProgressDialog bar example");
            progressDoalog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
            progressDoalog.show();
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        while (progressDoalog.getProgress() <= progressDoalog
                                .getMax()) {
                            Thread.sleep(200);
                            handle.sendMessage(handle.obtainMessage());
                            if (progressDoalog.getProgress() == progressDoalog
                                    .getMax()) {
                                progressDoalog.dismiss();
                            }
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }).start();
        }

        Handler handle = new Handler() {
            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                super.handleMessage(msg);
                progressDoalog.incrementProgressBy(1);
            }
        };
    });
}
```

}

Where can I add a code to open new activity when the ProgressDialog will be at 100%? Which and where exactly? Thanks for your help!

Comment: You need to put `startActivity` *somewhere*. Like where you dismiss the dialog, perhaps??

Answer (score 0):

You can't start an Activity from a Dialog, but what you can do is start the Activity from the old one using a OnDismissListener.

Take a look at the documemtation :

- https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/DialogInterface.OnDismissListener.html

I haven't noticed but you can check the progress in your Handler, check if it's 100%, dismiss the dialog and start the new Activity, remember that you gotta do this on the UI thread